# Pass variable to a .exe file from windows explorer

Tags: c#, parameters, windows-explorer

I have made a simple project in c#. To execute this program you have to pass it a string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime? dtDebut = null;
    if (args.Length > 0)
       dtDebut = DateTime.Parse(args[0]);

    DateTime? dtFin = null;
    if (args.Length > 1)
       dtFin = DateTime.Parse(args[1]);

    bool bGetDateFromTable = true;
    if (args.Length > 2)
       bGetDateFromTable = Boolean.Parse(args[2]);


    ObjetAXION objetAXION = recupererAxion();

    DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
    AXION.OLENotes.ScanFiles(objetAXION, dtDebut, dtFin, bGetDateFromTable);
    DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Temps du scan: " + (date2 - date1));
}
```

But how can I run the .exe file with a parameter from windows explorer ?

EDIT :

I will 100 % pass a date.

Comment: give a example for "a string", is it a filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a shortcut to your program. Edit the target of the shortcut (in the properties window of the shortcut) to include command line arguments.

Comment: Ok ! Ty for the suggestion but how can I include the parameter ? Ex of target : C:\Users\vincent.pare\Desktop\Projet\AXION_2013.06\Utilitaires\OLENotes\bin\Debug\OLENotes.exe

Comment: @VincP. just append it. use the `target` box as a command line.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Windows batch (text file with *.bat extension) and specify the call in there:

`MyProg.exe MyFirstArgument MySecondArgument`

That's it. See [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/) for further info.

Answer (score -1):

Open Regedit, find `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder`
You will find `shell\open\command` there with the defaultentry `%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe` <-- This is an good example, you can pass arguments there.

Copy `Folder` and rewrite it to your needs.

Another example is

- "C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"

You can pass arguments using "", %1 is the file.

BTW: This is not a Stackoverflow-able question.